# While loop loops everything but doesn't save

Tags: java, swing, dialog, joptionpane

I'm busy with an test phase for my bigger application, Hangman. But before I can move on to that code, I have to first figure out this code.

Now, I've created 2 Strings: 1 that's the word, and 1 to hide that word in the same number of letters the original word contains but with `'-'`. Now, someone gave me exactly the code I was looking for it reads the original string and the replaces the `'-'` in the second string at he same position depending if the char is in the letter, now I've created a loop to loop six times but the word doesn't keep the previous letter guessed (if guessed correct)

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyThisTest{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int error = 0;
    while(error < 6){
    char guessLetter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a letter:").charAt(0);



    String original = "painting";
    String secret = new String(new char[original.length()]).replace('\0', '-');

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(secret);
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++){
        if (original.charAt(i) == guessLetter){
            builder.setCharAt(i, guessLetter);
        }
    }

    secret = builder.toString();
    error++;
    System.out.println(secret);
    System.out.println(original);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change only 2 lines of code, put it before `while` cycle

```
String original = "painting";
String secret = new String(new char[original.length()]).replace('\0', '-');
```

Answer (score 1):

A problem above is that you're creating your `StringBuilder` inside of the while loop, so with each loop it gets re-created. The solution: Create your `StringBuilder` and secret word ***before*** the while loop. This way the `StringBuilder` gets created once and retains changes made in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with this

```
int error = 0;

String original = "painting";
String secret = new String(new char[original.length()]).replace('\0', '-');

while(error < 6)
{
   char guessLetter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a letter:").charAt(0);

   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(secret);
   for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++){
     if (original.charAt(i) == guessLetter){
        builder.setCharAt(i, guessLetter);
     }
   }

   secret = builder.toString();
   error++;

}
  System.out.println(secret);
  System.out.println(original);
```

Comment: why this downvote? Is it because of the last 2 lines? Otherwise it's not different from the accepted answer